# Как записать куки на ajax странице?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как записать куки на ajax странице без перезагрузки страницы?

```html
<?
// php файл , обновляется ajax
...


$rt = mysql_query("SELECT id from tab1 LIMIT 10 ");
while($id_array = mysql_fetch_array ($rt)) {
      $arr .= $id_array['id'].',';
}

?>

<script > 
Cookies.set( 'cook_1', "<?=$arr?>"  );  
</script>

<?

....
```

Comment: что такое "ajax страница"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это страница, загружаемая ajaxом.

Comment: Какое отношение приведённый код имеет к вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Используйте ajax:
 $.ajax({
     url: "file.php",
     type: " POST",
     async: false,
     cache: false,
     data:"dt=что-то-там"
 });
file.php:
 <?php
     $dt=$_POST['dt'];
     setcookie("gg",$dt);
 ?>
```

Comment: в вашем случае setcookie(); не пишется так как php setcookie() пишутся в <head>

Comment: если прописать так : setcookie("cook1",$_POST['dt'] , time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); То почти работает , данные в куку пишутся с отстованием в запрос .